¿Como lograr que un EditText no cambie el contenido del mismo?, solo si este no se encuentra vacio
Estoy haciendo un proyecto personal para aprender y este mismo contiene un login, al inicio tenia un problema y era que mis EditText cuando yo los presionaba me dejaba el texto que tenia puesto por default, es decir si en el EditText del usuario yo le tenia puesto un texto que diga Email y yo le presionaba y este seguía ahí. Lo solucione con las siguiente lineas de código:
user.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                user.setText("");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

Luego me surgió el problema de que mi EditText al momento de yo des-seleccionar o cambiar el Focus este seguia en blanco y lo que yo queria era que cuando yo me saliera del EditText este volviera a decir lo anterior, lo cual solucione con estas lineas de codigo:
user.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if (!b) {
                user.setText("Email");
            }
        }
    });

Pero ahora cuando yo escribo algo y por ejemplo selecciono el otro EditText de la contraseña, el texto que yo habia puesto en el EditText del usuario se sobreescribe al texto Email.
Habia pensado en poner algo como un condicional que tuviera como condición que si el EditText tenia como texto " " o vació este ejecutara esta parte del código:
user.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if (!b) {
                user.setText("Email");
            }
        }
    });

Pero la verdad es que soy bastante nuevo programando aplicaciones android en Java y no sabria que codigo poner.
De igual manera si pudieran sugerirme cambios a mi código lo agradecería, aunque claro, no es el punto principal de esta pregunta.
Anexo lo que llevo de código:
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText user, password;
Button button_login;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
boolean guardado = false;
TextView button_register;


@SuppressLint({"MissingInflatedId", "ClickableViewAccessibility"})
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    user = findViewById(R.id.user);
    password = findViewById(R.id.pass);
    button_login = findViewById(R.id.button_login_a_login);
    button_register = findViewById(R.id.textview_register_a_login);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    guardado = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("boolean", false);
    if (guardado){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,TransWelcome.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    button_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String user0 = user.getText().toString();
            String pass = password.getText().toString();
            boolean guardado = true;

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("user", user0);
            editor.putString("password", pass);
            editor.putBoolean("true", guardado);
            editor.apply();
            Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Eso tilin", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent welcome = new Intent(Login.this, TransWelcome.class);
            startActivity(welcome);
            finish();
        }
    });
    button_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, register.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
    user.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                user.setText("");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    user.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if (!b) {
                user.setText("Email");
            }
        }
    });

    password.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                password.setText("");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    password.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                if (!b) {
                    password.setText("Contraseña");
                }
            }
    });
}

}

EL problema es que cuando quitas el foco de la vista estas colocando un texto, pero esto incluso cuando tu EditText no tiene texto, en este caso valida también si los EditText no tiene texto mediante:
user.getText().toString().isEmpty()

ejemplo:
user.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
        if (user.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !b) {
            user.setText("Email");
        }
    }
});

